# Here I am. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I have been since nearly the beginning.
>   I endure nearly to the end of all time.
>
> At first, I was the one that came after.
>   Now, I am the one that comes before.
>
> I am $-1$.
>   I am $3$ of $7$.
>   I am sometimes confused for $5$ or $22$.
>   If $n$ is an integer, I am $2n -1$.
>
> I might be cut off the middle.
>   I might be part of an event, or merely part of the countdown.
>   I might be found in a lost flight of birds.
>   I might be the first and last thing you ever achieve.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are

> EVE

---

Clues:

I have been since nearly the beginning.

> Refers to the biblical Eve

I endure nearly to the end of all time.

> EVE(-r)

At first, I was the one that came after.

> Again, the biblical Eve, who came after Adam

Now, I am the one that comes before.

> Eve as in the day before, like today (X-mas eve, which also explains the title)

I am −1.

> If today is $0$, then eve is $-1$ (alternatively, the date of the eve is one less than the date of the actual day)

I am 3 of 7.

> Three letters of sEVEn

I am sometimes confused for 5 or 22.

> EVE can be anagrammed to VEE (V, five in Roman numerals, or the 22nd letter)

If n is an integer, I am 2n−1.

> $2n$ is even, so $2n-1$ is EVE(-n)

I might be cut off the middle.

> sEVEr (thanks @Ankoganit)

I might be part of an event, or merely part of the countdown.

> EVEnt, or part of the countdown to the following day (thanks @Rubio)

I might be found in a lost flight of birds.

> A flight of birds forms a VEE-shape, which anagrams (lost, in the confused sense) to EVE (thanks @Ankoganit)

I might be the first and last thing you ever achieve.

> EVEr achiEVE

Comment: "Cut off the middle" may be sEVEr, "lost flight..." may be referring to the 'vee'-shape of flight of birds.

Comment: @Ankoganit ah, sEVEr fits better. Not sure about "lost flight..." but your suggestion sounds plausible. Thanks!

Comment: If 2n is even, 2n-1 will be odd.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL this is tagged wordplay though, not mathematics

Comment: @Volatility I know that. Thats why I gave this an upvote. Seems very logical and appealing to me. :)

Comment: +1 from me on q and a, nice job